# Webpack uglify lots of legacy code in a clean way

Tags: javascript, webpack

Currently I am implementing webpack in our websites. The websites are static websites build on a php Zend2 architecture. We have lots and losts of vendor module installed and updated by composer. I have a working webpack solution, hence I feel like the code for legacy minification could be better. I have the following constraints

- Implement the old js code as is. I know rewriting to modules would be the best options but we have 100+ js files. The plan is to rewrite if the code needs to be touched.
- Legacy code should be minified based on a env.NODE_ENV flag
- current code splitting needs to be maintained

Currently the solution works as follow

1. Webpack switches to different js-entry files

   module.exports = env => {

   ```
   // webpack variables
   const isProduction = env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
   const assetJsPath = 'module/Eurocampings/assets/js/';
   const assetJsLegacyPath = 'module/Eurocampings/assets/js-legacy/';
   const webpackEntrySuffix = isProduction ? 'production' : 'develop';
   const paths = {
       entry: {
           main: `${assetJsPath}main.js`,
           mainLegacy: `${assetJsLegacyPath}webpack-entries-${webpackEntrySuffix}/main-legacy.js`,
           vendorBase: `${assetJsLegacyPath}webpack-entries-${webpackEntrySuffix}/vendor-base.js`,
           homepage: `${assetJsLegacyPath}webpack-entries-${webpackEntrySuffix}/homepage.js`,
           campsiteDetails: `${assetJsLegacyPath}webpack-entries-${webpackEntrySuffix}/campsite-details.js`,
           campsiteCompare: `${assetJsLegacyPath}webpack-entries-${webpackEntrySuffix}/campsite-compare.js`,
           campsiteChainDetails: `${assetJsLegacyPath}webpack-entries-${webpackEntrySuffix}/campsite-chain-details.js`,
           ajaxsolr: `${assetJsLegacyPath}webpack-entries-${webpackEntrySuffix}/ajaxsolr.js`,
           campsiteSearch: `${assetJsLegacyPath}webpack-entries-${webpackEntrySuffix}/campsite-search.js`,
           campsiteExtendedSearch: `${assetJsLegacyPath}webpack-entries-${webpackEntrySuffix}/campsite-extended-search.js`,
           picturefill: `${assetJsLegacyPath}webpack-entries-${webpackEntrySuffix}/picturefill.js`,
           destination: `${assetJsLegacyPath}webpack-entries-${webpackEntrySuffix}/destination.js`,
           styles: './module/Eurocampings/assets/scss/style.scss',
       },
       output: {
           folder: 'module/Eurocampings/dist',
       }
   };
   ```
2. Example of develop legacy entry without uglify-loader!

   ```
    // webpack entry for develop
   import exec from 'script-loader!../AcsiCampsiteSearch/DataLayerWidgetFactory.js';
   import exec from 'script-loader!../../../../../vendor/acsi/acsi-campsite/assets/js/acsiCampsiteCompare/acsiCampsiteCompare.js';
   import exec from 'script-loader!../../../../../vendor/acsi/acsi-campsite/assets/js/acsiCampsiteCompare/extensions/Label.js';
   import exec from 'script-loader!../../../../../vendor/acsi/acsi-campsite/assets/js/acsiCampsiteCompare/extensions/Selector.js';
   import exec from 'script-loader!../../../../../vendor/acsi/acsi-campsite/assets/js/acsiCampsiteCompare/extensions/CompareBox.js';
   import exec from 'script-loader!../../../../../vendor/acsi/acsi-campsite/assets/js/acsiCampsiteCompare/extensions/Cookie.js';
   import exec from 'script-loader!../../../../../vendor/acsi/acsi-campsite-search/assets/js/search.js';
   import exec from 'script-loader!../../../../../vendor/acsi/acsi-campsite-search/assets/js/map_initialization.js';
   ```
3. Example of production entry with uglify-loader!

   ```
   // webpack entry for develop
   import exec from 'script-loader!uglify-loader!../AcsiCampsiteSearch/DataLayerWidgetFactory.js';
   import exec from 'script-loader!uglify-loader!../../../../../vendor/acsi/acsi-campsite/assets/js/acsiCampsiteCompare/acsiCampsiteCompare.js';
   import exec from 'script-loader!uglify-loader!../../../../../vendor/acsi/acsi-campsite/assets/js/acsiCampsiteCompare/extensions/Label.js';
   import exec from 'script-loader!uglify-loader!../../../../../vendor/acsi/acsi-campsite/assets/js/acsiCampsiteCompare/extensions/Selector.js';
   import exec from 'script-loader!uglify-loader!../../../../../vendor/acsi/acsi-campsite/assets/js/acsiCampsiteCompare/extensions/CompareBox.js';
   import exec from 'script-loader!uglify-loader!../../../../../vendor/acsi/acsi-campsite/assets/js/acsiCampsiteCompare/extensions/Cookie.js';
   import exec from 'script-loader!uglify-loader!../../../../../vendor/acsi/acsi-campsite-search/assets/js/search.js';
   import exec from 'script-loader!uglify-loader!../../../../../vendor/acsi/acsi-campsite-search/assets/js/map_initialization.js';
   ```

Comment: Write a script to change the old files to module format.

Comment: I have several hundred js files al dependent on jQuery and lots of global variables. I do not think that will work i a short time